# Understanding pythons reverse slice ( [::-1] )

Tags: python, slice

I always thought that omitting arguments in the python slice operation would result into:

- start = `0`
- end = `len(lst)`
- step = `1`

That holds true if the step is positive, but as soon as the step is negative, like in the "reverse slice" `[::-1]`, omitting start/end results in:

- start = `len(lst)-1`
- end = `None`

Is this a special case, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is *always* `None`; it is up to the type to determine how to handle `None` for any of the 3 values. The `list` object is simply passed a `slice(None, None, -1)` object in this case.

See footnote 5 to the operations table in the [sequence types documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) for how Python's default sequence types (including list objects) interpret these:

> `s[i:j:k]`
>   5. *[...]* If *i* or *j* are omitted or `None`, they become “end” values (which end depends on the sign of *k*).

So the defaults are dependent on the sign of the step value; if negative the ends are reversed. For `[::-1]` the end values are `len(s) - 1` and `-1` (absolute, not relative to the end), respectively, because the step is negative.

Comment: Why do you say -1 and not None for j?

Comment: @wim: yes, because the end value is *not included in the slice*. If you set it to `0` you won't get that first element.

Comment: @wim: note that if you used `s[len(s) - 1:-1:-1]` the value for `j` is taken relative to the length and it won't work; only `None` or leaving it empty would let you include the first element.

Comment: I see what you mean.  It's a bit confusing, because we never use -1 to mean that in a slice

Comment: I only read the "What's new in Python 2.3" article that introduced the extended slice syntax. Thank you for a better reference!